# Features of a facebook messenger chatbox

Tags: facebook

Firstly, I am a telecommunications engineering student and I am doing an investigation about how can I implement different types of features for chatbots on Facebook Messenger.
I want to include a survey (I've made my survey at a url) on chatbot but I would like to respond that survey on THAT CHATBOT! I don't want to click on my url and then a new page is opened for respond the survey.

For example: 
I have two things: 
    -By one side: My url with my survey.
    -By other side: My Chatbot.
Okey, now someone is going to talk to me through my chatbot and I want him to do my survey, so, how can I make him my survey on chatbot? It's possible?
I don't want make him click on my url that contains the survey and a new page opens!.

Regards,
Manuel.

Comment: No, you can't. Your "survey" is only a survey on your end - from the messenger perspective, it is just an external website. If you want survey functionality "on" messenger - then you will have to implement it _in_ messenger, using the functionality and templates it offers.

Comment: And what about that? https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Facebook-Messenger

Comment: What about it? _“People take the survey by chatting with SurveyMonkey in Messenger”_